# Persistent Retryable Task Library

Tags: java, scala, akka

I want to implement an asynchronous retry mechanism that persists in the logic of retry and do its jobs until success. Is there any production-ready library?

Comment: I thought about Akka Persistence and quick googling shows that people already tried to implement something: https://gist.github.com/eliseealex/eb096dc520df3935f3008c70c1a2a70f

Comment: I wanna a production-ready library like Quartz, not an experimental code